# Relink .form and .java files in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I just opened a project I did a year ago in Netbeans to continue development on it. This project used Netbeans GUI builder and swing. When I open it some of the GUI JPanels don't let me enter design view to change the GUI with Netbeans' builder. Some of the GUI windows do let me open design view. For the ones that I can't enter design view, I can see the corresponding .form files under the project source. It's weird because some of them work and others don't.

I am assuming that the reason I can't enter design view is because I can see these form files, does this mean they are not linked with the corresponding .java file? Is there a way to re-link these files?

I would like to know how to access design view for these files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason some of the .form files had changed the first letter to lower case, simply renaming the file to be the same name as the corresponding .java files and restarting Netbeans fixed the issue.

i.e.

```
file.form
```

to

```
File.form
```

for

```
File.java
```